# jQuery Date Picker popup TO field Calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a plugin to display a Date Range calendar on my website using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox).

I am quite new to jQuery and find it hard to figure out the usage of [Methods](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html).

When a user selects the `FROM` date, I want to popup the `TO` date Calendar automatically. Currently I have turned on `autoclose` so the calendar disappears once the `FROM` date is selected, but cant figure out how to popup the `TO` calendar.

Comment: The calendar you are talking about is DateRange picker.

Comment: Yes it is. I didnt know DateRange picker is popular

Comment: Select the From Type "Range" at top..

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am sending you my HTML . 
first of all we need to add some class for our from date input and to date input like this .

add class `fromdate`  for from date input 
add class `todate` for to date input

```
<div id="sandbox-container">
            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fromdate" name="start" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control todate" name="end" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

then just add the below script, and i hope its helps you and give you your desire output.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
        });

        $(document).on('change', '.input-daterange > .fromdate', function (e) {
           $(".todate").focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code i have used. Just set the paths for CSS and js accordingly yours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <link id="bs-css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link id="bsdp-css" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <div id="sandbox-container">
            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fromdate" name="start" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control todate" name="end" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
        });

        $(document).on('change', '.input-daterange > .fromdate', function (e) {
           $(".todate").focus();
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.` $(".todate").focus();` worked inside the .on("changeDate", function() {
   console.log('t');
   $("#ToDate").focus();
   
  });

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I hope you are looking for this only

Comment: Hi Punit. I already have that. I just want to kwo how to popup the TO field calendar once the FROM date is selected

Comment: ok ,. what i understand is you want to like , when any user select the "From" date then from date-picker should be closed and date picker for "To" should be opened automatically .  am i right ?

Comment: Yep. Thats it. How do i do it? :)

Comment: is your code live ? or possible that you can create fiddle ?

Comment: I am trying to get this fiddle working but it doesnt work : https://jsfiddle.net/8gmhomjg/1/

Comment: At least if I can perform a proper click on the TO field, the calendar will popup. But all the click functions i use dont work

Comment: Hello , i tried my self for doing as what you want,. please check my another answer.